# Why is my json not appearing in my params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

In my Rails app, I have:

**routes.rb:**

```
  resources :tasks, :defaults => {:format => 'json'}, :except => [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
    member do
      get :to_chrome
      post :from_chrome
    end
  end
```

**mime_types.rb:**

```
Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls
Mime::Type.register "application/json", :json
```

**tasks_controller.rb:**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?

  def to_chrome
    @survey = Survey.find(params["id"])
      @survey = Survey.last
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {render_for_api :private, :json => @survey}
      end
    end
  end

  def from_chrome
    binding.pry_remote
    render :nothing => true
  end

  protected

  def json_request?
    request.format.json?
  end

end
```

`to_chrome` is working fine.

I'm trying to trigger `from_chrome` from Postman with the following settings:

**URL:** http://localhost:3000/tasks/2452456/from_chrome

**Verb:** Post

**Body:** "John Rambo", time:"2pm"

(have also tried wrapping the entire string in single quotes)

**Body format:** raw JSON (application/json)

**Header 1:** Accept: application/json

**Header 2:** Content-Type: application/json

In Postman, I'm getting back a 200 response.

But in Rails, when I inspect `params` inside `from_chrome`, I just see:

```
{"format"=>"json", "controller"=>"tasks", "action"=>"from_chrome", "id"=>"2452456"}
```

Where's my Json?

Thanks,

Steven.

Comment: You don't have to register the JSON mime type - Rails already does that for you. You can also use  `only: []` instead of `except => [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I just found the json in `request.body.read`.